# How can i establish a socket connection to an .onion url using SilverTunnel-NG on Android Studio? Is there any alternative?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to use silvertunnel-ng in order to connect to a hidden service which i created with tor. If i use the code bellow from netbeans i can connect to the socket using the .onion url.

```
final String HOST = "xw7pdude7qmfqiqim67f.onion";
final TcpipNetAddress proxyTcpipNetAddress = new TcpipNetAddress(HOST, 1444);
System.out.println("Connecting ");
socket = NetFactory.getInstance().getNetLayerById(NetLayerIDs.TOR_OVER_TLS_OVER_TCPIP).createNetSocket(null, null, proxyTcpipNetAddress);
System.out.println("Connected");
```

the libraries that i use are:

- netlib-0.0.3.jar
- bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar
- bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar
- httpclient-4.1.2.jar
- httpcore-4.1.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
- slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar

when i transfer the project to android studio it works only if i use

- netlib-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
- sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
- slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar

but the connection fails with a timeout error like that

```
I/ControlNetSocketThread﹕ send timeout to ControlNetSocket(LoggingNetSocket(Socket2NetSocket(Socket[address=/82.94.251.203,port=80,localPort=43309]))): overall timeout reached
```

Has anyone managed to connect to an .onion url using silvertunnel-ng on android studio? Which libraries should i use? Is there an alternative to silvertunnel-ng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a new snapshot of silvertunnel-ng released a few days ago and the problem is solved. i confirm that connecting to tor from android using silvertunnel-ng is possible.